# Does using of a laptop as a WiFi hotspot have any adverse effects on the laptop's WiFi adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, hotspot

Because I do not have a 3G router and I have a 3G modem I use my laptop as a WiFi router to be able to connect my mobile over WiFi.

Is there any adverse effect on the laptop WiFi caused by using it as a hotspot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for hardware, there shouldn't be any issues that are caused by using your laptop as a Wifi hotspot.

You should, however, make sure you properly configure security settings for your WiFi to prevent others from connecting to your WiFi. Doing so would not only enable them to use your Internet connection (possibly using up your data volume) but might also enable others to break into your laptop.

Things to do specifically:

- Enable WPA and specify a password. (Don't use WEP as it is insecure and has sucessfully been broken into.)
- Make sure you need to use a password to log on to your laptop.
- If you have any network shares on your laptop, make sure they can only be accessed by authenticated users.

Comment: ThankYou for your answer and i had taken all precautionary measures mentioned above.